# How do I create some objects to store in an arrayList, which is a attribute of sub class, from a parent class in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, initialization

So I have 3 classes, Lair, LairLocation & Minion. I created an ArrayList, which is supposed to store Minion objects, and this is an attribute of LairLocation. I'm supposed to create some objects to store in ArrayList, from the parent class Lair. Both LairLocation and Minion and sub-classes of Lair.

Whenever I try to create objects to store in ArrayList form my parent, I keep getting an error saying 'minion cannot be resolved' and telling me to create a local variable etc. Please help

```
LairLocation 

'''
public class LairLocations extends Lair
{
        public static ArrayList<Minion> minions = new ArrayList<Minion>();
}
'''

Lair

'''
public class Lair
{
        public void createMinions() 
    {
        minions.add("12", "Mine", "Me");//This is giving me the error 
    }
}
'''

Minion
'''
public class Minion extends Lair
{

    private String id;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;

    public Minion(String Id, String fName, String lName) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a field of a subclass from its parent class. This does not work this way.

You can only access fields of a parent class (if they're public or protected).

So, you either have to move your `minions` field to the parent class `Lair` (and make it non-static, by the way), or access this object via LairLocation class: `LairLocation.minions()` (if the field is supposed to be static).

Also, this line of code is incorrect: `minions.add("12", "Mine", "Me");`

The `add()` method accepts only one element.

It should probably be: `minions.add(new Minion("12", "Mine", "Me"));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `new Minion()` to get a new minion.

```
minions.add( new Minion( "12", "Mine", "Me") );
```